Is every summand of $R_{R}$ isomorphic to a direct summand from the decomposition $R= eR \oplus (e-1)R$?
I've seen quite a lot on ring theory, modules and algebra literature that  when a ring is thought as a right(left) module, i.e $R_{R}$, then every direct summand of $R_{R}$ is thought as isomorphic to a direct summand of a decomposition $R= eR \oplus (e-1)R$ where $e$ and $e-1$ are idempotents of $R$, obviously. So if I stated correctly the statement, I was wondering why this happens (any reference of sketch of the proof would be appreciated), or if maybe I'm missing out some hypothesis. So far I skim read the wiki article on idempotents (of a ring), and the most similar statement is that a ring being semi-perfect is equivalent to having a decomposition $R= e_{1} R \oplus.......\oplus e_{n}R$ where all the $e_{i}$'s are local idempotents. I'm quite a sure that we dont need in my case the requirements of $R$ semi-perfect and the idempotents locals.

I'm not sure I understand what it is you are asking. Are you looking for a proof that every direct sum decomposition of $R_R$ comes from orthogonal idempotents summing to 1 ?

@Olivier_Bégassat Yes, I think so. I've seen some proofs use the thing I mentioned in my question but I'm not sure about where that statement comes from.  Seems like what you mentioned is what I'm looking to prove . Merci pour lire ma question.

Does the following help ? https://mathstrek.blog/2015/03/02/idempotents-and-decomposition/
